# Named scope with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some trouble with my named scope.

```
def self.by_status(status)
    arr = status.split(',').map{ |s| s }        
    logger.debug "RESULT: #{arr.inspect}"
    where(status: arr)
end
```

When I call this scope with more than one value, the result of arr = `["New", "Open"]`

This does not return any results, while it should. If I try this command in the console: `Shipment.where(status: ['New', 'Open'])` I get the results that I'm expecting.

Am I missing something here?

Edit (added the call of the class method ):

```
def self.to_csv(options = {}, vendor_id, status)
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names

    if !vendor_id.blank? && status.blank?
            by_vendor_id(vendor_id).each do |product|
            csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      elsif !vendor_id.blank? && !status.blank?
            by_vendor_id(vendor_id).by_status(status).each do |product|
            csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      elsif vendor_id.blank? && !status.blank?
        logger.debug "by_status result: #{by_status(status).inspect}"
            by_status(status).each do |product|
            csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end      
      else  
        all.each do |product|
            csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok can you show how are you calling the class method `by_status` in your app. By the way what you have is called _class method_, not a _named scope_. Read [this](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/) to know why.

Comment: I will update my post with my call. The context is, I'm passing the parameters from my datatable to my controller and then to my model. I'm trying to use the parameters to export to csv.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your model:

```
scope :by_status, ->(*statuses) { where(status: statuses) }
```

Then in your code you can call:

```
Shipment.by_status('New', 'Open')
```

This has the flexibility to just take one argument, too:

```
Shipment.by_status('New')
```

Comment: My input comes from a parameter like this: 'Open, New', so I have to split them and then pass them to the scope. This isn't working unfortunately

Comment: Then maybe you just need to include a space in your `#split`: `split(', ')`

Comment: The split works, but the scope for some reason doesnt :(